# I try to run gradlew genSource

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

```
C:\Users\boeec\OneDrive\Desktop\MC Modding\krypton>gradlew genSource

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\boeec\OneDrive\Desktop\MC Modding\krypton\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '0.8-SNAPSHOT']
> Failed to apply plugin 'fabric-loom'.
   > You are using an outdated version of Java (8). Java 16 or higher is required.
     The JAVA_HOME environment variable is currently set to (C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.292.10-hotspot\).

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 706ms
```

Edit: New Error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 4 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :
Fabric Loom: 0.8.21

> Task :genSources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':genSources'.
> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\boeec\.gradle\caches\fabric-loom\1.16.4-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.4+build.9-v2\minecraft-1.16.4-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.4+build.9-v2.jar: Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei z
ugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: *"You are using an outdated version of Java (8). Java 16 or higher is required."*: Consider to upgrade your java installation.

Comment: I updated it, but it do not work.

Comment: Do you get a new error message? If so, please [add it to your question above](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68612906/edit) - you need to install this version: https://jdk.java.net/16/

Comment: I did it but now I have this new error.

Comment: It looks like some process (likely another Gradle daemon) still locks some jar files (weird, I woudln't expect that lock to be exclusive). Try [stopping all running Gradle daemons](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:stopping_an_existing_daemon) using `gradlew --stop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Answer from comment)*

For the first error `You are using an outdated version of Java`, you have to upgrade your Java version from 1.8 to 1.16.

Then, for the second error `java.nio.file.FileSystemException` :

[Stop all running gradle daemons](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:stopping_an_existing_daemon) thanks to `gradlew --stop` command.